# Не могу использовать xlink и xpointer в реальном проекте

Tags: html, xml

Я читал наверно 4 книги по xml. Во всех есть подробное объяснение xlink и xpointer, но ни в одной не рассказано, как я могу использовать их в реальном проекте (например, чтобы эти ссылки отображались в браузерах).

Я использовал css или xsl, но не мог делать так, чтобы например элемент `<link xlink...> my link </link>` в xml-е, который представлияет собой "simple xlink", отображался в браузере как ссылка "my link" а не простой текст "my link".

Comment: Используйте символы ` для выделения кода, xml, html.

Comment: В браузерах нет поддержки `xlink`. Хотите рабочие ссылки - используйте элемент `<a>`.

Comment: Вы используете xsl-трансформацию в браузере? Откажитесь от этого. В браузерах поддерживается только старая версия xslt 1.0, Хотя уже есть версии 2 и 3. Скоро поддержка xsl совсем будет убрана из браузеров. / Делайте преобразования xml в html на сервере. И передавайте на клиента готовую страницу html.

Comment: как понимаю xlink, xpointer, xpath и xsl устарели? хотите сказать работать с xml спомошю JAXP или JAXB?

Comment: Они не устарели. Просто они не применяются непосредственно в браузерах.

Comment: болшое спасибо за ответы

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а позвольте поинтересоваться, откуда информация про «поддержка xsl совсем будет убрана из браузеров»? Я наоборот нашёл информацию о том, что [убирать ничего не будут](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=514995)

Comment: @andreymal - ну, разговоры про это идут уже много лет. Значит решили оставить. Хорошо, буду знать.